# Restricting internet Traffic to a website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

We have a website that we want to limit traffic to so that only admin can access the website. We don't have DNS set up for it. For instance, http://01.235.06.30:7000 and http://01.235.06.30:7000/api both allow traffic routing from the internet (users IPs).

I want  http://01.235.06.30:7000 to be exposed to only a specific user's IP and block other user's IP, but keep  http://01.235.06.30:7000/api exposed to all users since it's the endpoint that user's will hit.

So far, I haven't find any helpful resources online. I have thought about using Application Load Balancer, but I'm not sure how that will work.

Do you think this will be possible and if so, how?

Comment: Why is this tagged with all 3 major cloud platforms (GCP, AWS, and Azure)? You're only using one....

Comment: Because I believe the question is not limited to AWS and I will still appreciate the ideas or answers from other people who have done something similar in other platforms.

Comment: The three platforms are _very_ different though - besides, using IP filtering is **not** a good way to secure a web-application like this. Why aren't you using IAM/AAD instead?

Comment: Okay, I've updated the tags. The IP in the question is not the original Ip, it an example. By IAM, Do you mean Identity and Access Management for the websites?

Comment: You would like a site to be "exposed to only Admin" -- but what is "Admin"? How do users authenticate to be recognised as "Admin"? Networks are very good at allowing/block traffic based on IP address, but they cannot identify 'users' -- this would need to be done at the application level.

Comment: To recognize only admin user's IP and block other user's IP

Comment: Client IP addresses aren't identities and should not be used as an alternative to strong user/device authentication. Having said that, EC2 security groups can [restrict inbound traffic](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-block-or-allow-ips/#:~:text=To%20allow%20or%20block%20specific,addresses%20from%20accessing%20your%20resources.) to specific IP addresses as can [WAF and ALB](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/12/AWS-WAF-now-available-on-Application-Load-Balancer/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering traffic based on source IP and requested HTTP content would be the job of a firewall. It can't be done through Route 53, since Route 53 does the domain name resolution and does not deal with the HTTP layer. AWS web application firewall can accomplish the behavior you describe https://aws.amazon.com/waf/